# Achievement Completion Handler does not detect when no Internet connection is available

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am adding Game Center Achievements to the game i am developing
I am now trying to manage those cases in which an error occurs. The Apple Game Kit Dev. guide says that this can be done by means of the following code

```
[achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){ 
if (error != nil) {
// Retain the achievement object and try again later (not shown).
}}]
```

you associate to your achievement when you try yo add it.

I am therefore trying to cause an error.

To this end I start the game with my WIFI enabled, I turn off the WIFI connection and play with the game to achieve an achievement.

Unfortunately I always get an error= nil

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
[achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){ 
   if ([[error loacalizedDescription] isEqualToString: "no internet connection"]) {
         NSLog("Connection failed");
    }
}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

reading http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/Reference/Reference.html :

> error: If the operation was successful, this value is nil; otherwise,
>   this parameter holds an object that describes the problem that
>   occurred.

About network error:

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the background reporting task automatically
>   handles network errors on your game’s behalf.

If i understand correct network errors are managed for you, nothing to do at application level.